# Filter Dropdown MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC. I want to filter my table using parameter from Dropdownlist:

My Model:

```
public class Document
{
    [Key]
    public int MasterAPID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }
    public MasterCompany MasterCompany { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
}

public class MasterCompany
{
    [Key]
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
private IRMAContext db = new IRMAContext();

// GET: MasterAPs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.CompanyID = new SelectList(db.MasterCompanies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");

    var masterAPs = db.MasterAPs.Include(m => m.MasterCompany);
    return View(masterAPs.ToList());
}
```

My View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownList("oYear", Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString() }), "Select Year", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownList("oMonth", Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString("00") }), "Select Month", new { @class = "form-control" })
<br>
<button type="submit">View</button>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DocumentNumber)
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So On the table itself, I won't show the 3 parameters. Only the `DocumentNumber` field. When user select `company`, `year`, `month` then click the View button, automatically the table will only show the data that base on the selected parameter.

How can I achieve this thing?
really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another action on your controller, and another view matching that action. For example:

```
// GET: Detials
public ActionResult Details(int companyId)
{
ViewBag.CompanyID = new SelectList(db.MasterCompanies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");

var specificCompany = db.MasterAPs.Include(m => m.MasterCompany).Where(c => c.Id == companyId);
return View(specificCompany);
}
```

And edit the new Details.cshtml as needed with the data passed.

Comment: and what should i put on button view?

Comment: You can put    `<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "YourControllerName", new { companyId= @item.CompanyId})">View Details</a>`